# Meteor mdg-camera quality is poor

Tags: meteor, camera

I am using meteor package mdg:camera to access my phone camera and click pics. But the image quality is poor and the height and width are not as mentioned. Take photo or cancel options dont even appear on the scree. Here is the code

```
'click .uploadPic' : function(event, template){
    var check = Template.instance().data;
    event.preventDefault();
    var cameraOptions = {
        width: 800,
        height: 600

    };
    MeteorCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function (error, data) {
        if(!error){
            ChatMessages.insert({
                createdAt : new Date(),
                createdBy : Meteor.userId(),
                doubtName : check,
                img : data
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the camera working on phone (redmi note 3)
[image]

I know its a very basic mistake I am making but cant figure out what it is.

Comment: Looks like ```mdg:camera``` is mostly for demo purposes only. Check [this](https://forums.meteor.com/t/mdg-camera-image-quality/19410/6) thread for more information

Comment: hmm, then what should i use for an app that i want to deploy. mdg:camera is sureshot not a good option to proceed with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `quality` option, as mentioned in this [docs](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:camera)

```
'click .uploadPic' : function(event, template){
    var check = Template.instance().data;
    event.preventDefault();
    var cameraOptions = {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        quality: 100
    };
    MeteorCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function (error, data) {
        if(!error){
            ChatMessages.insert({
                createdAt : new Date(),
                createdBy : Meteor.userId(),
                doubtName : check,
                img : data
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: doesn't help. seems the same to naked eye

Comment: Look like focus is not working or camera is simply dirty. Is preview looks different from result?

Comment: no issues with camera i guess. I checked it on multiple devices. result is same as the preview.

Comment: [Here is official cordova plugin docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) where is mentioned an issue with using `DATA_URL` as `destinationType`, while Meteor's package [uses it](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/blob/master/packages/mdg:camera/photo-cordova.js#L21), might be a reason for quality issue. Also there is mentioned what poor photo quality may happen on old devices (is this may be your case)?